# Continuously logging the amperage data coming from a Raspi HAT problem

Tags: python, csv, logging, raspberry-pi

I am fairly new to python, and coding in general, and I am tasked to write a program to set an output A and  continuously log the A data that is coming from a HAT on a raspberry Pi model 4b running Ubuntu, program which I will use for my Master thesis. I have the part of the program that does set the A, but I have not been successful in making a loop that saves the data in a file every second. I have both tried saving the data in a .csv format and in a .txt one, but both to no avail, as the file is created, but it is always empty. Also, the loop is not closed, as we want to have it continuously running until we decide to hit stop. Until now I have stopped the program by hitting "stop" in the program I am writing the code in (Thonny), as I habe tried with the keyboard library to code it stopping once a specific key was pressed to no avail.

```
import megaind #HAT library
from datetime import date #time library for file name
import schedule #for iteration
import time
amperage = input("Input the desired amperage.The input must be between 4 and 20:\n") #amperage imput
amperage = float(amperage)
while amperage < 4.0 or amperage > 20.0 : #while statement that controls if the amperage value is between the parameters
    amperage = input("please imput a number between 4 and 20:\n")
    amperage = float(amperage)
megaind.set4_20Out(0,1,amperage) #sets the 1st output pin to the amperage value
today = date.today() #string variable with its contents as today's date
time_write = 0
in_amperage = 0
def time_fun(): #function that writes seconds and input value
    global time_write
    global in_amperage
    time_write += 1
    in_amperage = megaind.get4_20In(0,1)
    txtfile.write("'{0}','{1}'\n".format(time_write, in_amperage))
with open('/home/laserlab/Desktop/discharge files/%s.txt' % today, 'a') as txtfile: #writes the data in a csv file
    while True:
        schedule.every(1).seconds.do(time_fun) #iterates each second
        while True:
            schedule.run_pending()
            time.sleep(1)
```

This is me trying to save it as a txt file

```
import megaind #HAT library
from datetime import date #time library for file name
import csv #for file writing
import schedule #for iteration
import time
amperage = input("Input the desired amperage.The input must be between 4 and 20:\n") #amperage imput
amperage = float(amperage)
while amperage < 4.0 or amperage > 20.0 : #while statement that controls if the amperage value is between the parameters
    amperage = input("please imput a number between 4 and 20:\n")
    amperage = float(amperage)
megaind.set4_20Out(0,1,amperage) #sets the 1st output pin to the amperage value
today = date.today() #string variable with its contents as today's date
time_write = 0
def time_fun(): #function that writes seconds and input value
    global time_write
    time_write += 1
    in_amperage = megaind.get4_20In(0,1)
with open('/home/laserlab/Desktop/discharge files/%s.csv' % today, 'a') as csvfile: #writes the data in a csv file
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    while True:
        line_amp = ['time_write','in_amperage']
        writer.writerow(line_amp)
        schedule.every(1).seconds.do(time_fun) #iterates each second
        while True:
            schedule.run_pending()
            time.sleep(1)
```

This is instead trying to save it as a csv file.
The format of the file is not important, as in the end it will all be imported in either R or excel, so I am open to suggestions of any kind. Also, the megaind library is the one provided by the HAT manifacturer that I am using to get the data from said device. I have tried both with the linux terminal and from the program itself, and it is getting the data from the HAT, so the issue doesn't lay there.
I am probably doing something wrong that will be apparent to people more experienced than me, but I cannot see what that might be. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: files are empty or contains zeros?

Comment: Have you tried calling `csvfile.flush()` after the `writer.writerow()` call. It could be that the file write is still in memory.

Comment: The files are empty, not with zeroes.

I will try what cguk70 proposed tomorrow once I get back to the lab, thanks!